# String delimited regular expression

Tags: java, regex, parsing, bbcode

I'm trying to build a bbcode parser, but I'm having quite some problems figuring out how to avoid matching too widely. For example I want to implement a [list] to  conversion like this:

```
\[list\](.*)\[/list\]
```

would be replaced by this:

```
<ul>$1</ul>
```

This works fine, except if I have two lists where the regular expression matches the beginning tag of the first list and the ending tag of the second. So this

```
[list]list1[/list] [list]list2[/list]
```

becomes this:

```
<ul>list1[/list] [list]list2</ul>
```

which produces really ugly output. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Better build a real parser than this regex pseudo parser. At least when you want nested lists you will see that regular expressions are not the answer to every question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you are doing is not just a lightweight hack, but something more permanent, you probably want to move to a real parser. Regexps in Java are particularly slow (even with precompiled patterns) and matching nested constructs (especially *different* nested contructs like "foo [u][i] bar [s]baz[/s][/i][/u]" ) is going to be a royal pain.

Instead, try using a state-based parser, that repeatedly cuts your sentence in sections like "foo " / (u) / "[i] bar [s]baz[/s][/i][/u]", and maintains a set of states that flip whenever you encounter the matching construct delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, do you know some resources or a working example of such a parser? Speed really is my main concern ^^

Comment: Java's built-in regexes are plenty fast enough if you know what you're doing. I agree that regexes are not the right tool for this job, but performance is not the reason.

Comment: Even something as simple as matching a prefix with a precompiled Java regexp is painfully slow (printing all matching lines from a file, with a regexp like "^mystring": two orders of magnitude compared to a simple startswith, an order of magnitude compared with the same program in Perl... wtf?)

Answer (score 8):

The method you're using may not end up being a particularly good approach, but to solve that specific problem, just change to non-greedy matching:

```
\[list\](.*?)\[\/list\]
```

Note that this way will have trouble with nested lists instead of back-to-back ones.